# To have 2 decimal places in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset with values

```
1234.1 
777777 
65797667.11
```

The expected output is

```
1234.10
777777.00
65797667.11
```

what function can we use to get the expected output, round is not required

Answer (score 2):

```
format variable_name size_of_whole_number_part.size_of_fractional_part;
```

So for your data:

```
format var_name 8.2;
```